# Find all vertices reachable from a vertex of a directed graph in time O(|E| + |V|)

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

Where |E| denotes the number of edges, |V| the number of vertices.

My idea is to use depth-first search on the given vertex to find all vertices reachable from it. However as far as my understanding goes, performing depth-first search from only one vertex requires O(1 + out-degree(u)) time, where u is the vertex in question.

Assuming that depth-first search is the answer, why would I have to perform a full O(|V| + |E|) search?

Comment: DFS from only one vertex requires O(|E|). Consider a complete graph as the worst case, where DFS would traverse every edge even from a single vertex. You should be aware that "all vertices reachable" means directly or indirectly via another vertex, i.e. transitive.

Answer (score 2):

If you perform only one step of the DFS then it is O(1 + outdegree(v)), nevertheless, that will only get you the vertices that are reachable from v at one step, but not all the vertices that you may reach.

Think of the recursion, in order to retrieve all reachable vertices you should perform another recursive DFS search for each reached vertex. In the worst case you will reach all vertices and thus you will have the sum of O(1+outdegree(v)) for each vertex, so you will traverse all the edges of the graph and get O(|V|+|E|).

Answer (score 1):

Because

(1) you must perform a depth-first search not only in the initial vertex, but also in all vertices that are directly connected to it, and in all vertices those vertices are connected to, and so on.

(2) in the worst case, all the vertices will be reachable from the initial one, and it will be equivalent to perform a full DFS.

Comment: In the case I'm studying, DFS is implemented using a recursive dfsFromVertex(v) function which has stated time Ɵ(1 + out-degree(v)). Does this mean that Ɵ(1 + out-degree(v)) = Ɵ(|V| + |E|) in the worse case? This part confuses me, as out-degree(v) can be |V| at most. I'm guessing that I am wrongly attributing Ɵ(1 + out-degree(v)) to be the time complexity of the entire recursion, whereas maybe it is the runtime of only one iteration of the recursion.

Comment: yes, Ɵ(1 + out-degree(v)) for each vertex will be Ɵ(|V| + |E|) in total. A very well known graph theory theorem states that the sum of all the degrees of all the vertices in every graph is 2|E|. And yes, this Ɵ(1 + out-degree(v)) is for every recursive step, and you will have exactly one recursive step for each vertex.